# disable .recycle feature for samba shares

Tags: samba, disk-space-utilization

I had a pretty big scare when my company file server filled up.

after tacking down the source I discovered that there is a .recycle folder that keeps ALL  the files ever deleted (which is also hidden)

Is there anyway to disable this feature?

or periodically run a command that will delete all the junk?

Edit

example of my smb.conf

```
 [homes]
            comment = Home
            path = /home/%S/smbhome
            browseable = no
            writable = yes
            read only = no

 -->*          veto files = /.recycle/
 -->           vfs objects = recycle
 -->                   recycle:keeptree=True
 -->                   recycle:versions=True
 -->                   recycle:touch=True
            hide dot files = yes

            force directory mode = 0770
            force create mode = 0660
            force group = grp-it

            valid users = @grp-it, %S
            invalid users =
```

Should i just comment out these lines.

what about VETO files? (marked *)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have got the Samba [Recycle](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_recycle.8.html) plugin configured. This copies files to a .recycle directory when they are deleted through a Samba share.

The plugin is enabled using the [`vfs objects`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#VFSOBJECTS) share configuration option in `smb.conf`. To disable it find the `vfs objects` configuration options and remove `recycle` from the value (or remove the option completely if it only references `recycle`). You'll also want to get rid of any options that are prefixed `recycle:`.

We use a daily cron job like the following to delete files in .recycle older than 10 days and clean up empty directories:

```
#!/bin/sh

for d in /home/*/.recycle 
do
  if [ -d "$d" ]
  then
    tmpreaper --mtime-dir --symlinks 10d "$d"
    find "$d" -depth -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs --null --no-run-if-empty rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
  fi
done
```

This script uses the [tmpreaper](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/tmpreaper) package.

The [`veto files`](http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#VETOFILES) option is preventing users from seeing or accessing the `.recycle` directories through the file shares.

If you want to disable the Recycle plugin, then either remove or comment out all the lines that you have highlighted apart from the `veto files` line. To allow users to see and access directories named `.recycle`, then remove or comment out the `veto files` line too.